# Change Class Dynamically with Javascript after Value has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code here that I have been working with to make the css class change dynamically. When I load the page with this code it just keeps the class as 'cart' whenever the span'cart count' is greater than 0. I am not sure if something is not loading correctly.

http://store.revivesalonsf.com

Here is the JSFiddle example I have been working with to do the same thing. Any thoughts on how to make this work? Any guidance is appreciated as I am slowly but surly learning js.

http://jsfiddle.net/xs9e6moL/65/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span").each(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).text()) > 0) {
      $(this).parent().find('a').removeClass("cart");
      $(this).parent().find('a').addClass("cart-full");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.cart-full {
  border: 2px solid red
}

.cartContainer {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart-summary">
  <div class="cartContainer">
    <span class="cart-summary__count" data-v-observable="cart-count">0</span>
    <a href class="cart">example.com</a>
  </div>
  <div class="cartContainer">
    <span class="cart-summary__count" data-v-observable="cart-count">1</span>
    <a href class="cart">example1.com</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the actual expected behaviour? It works in Chrome - also your fiddle is set up wrong. Look at the "In Head" and the added jQuery here: http://jsfiddle.net/u6jobwaa/

Comment: It's working fine. By the way, you can reduce your codes: $(this).parent().find('a').removeClass("cart").addClass("cart-full");

Comment: or `$(this).next().toggleClass("cart-full",parseInt($(this).text(),10));`

Comment: Here is the page that is not working. The cart up at the top is not working when an item is added to the cart.    http://store.revivesalonsf.com

I only have access to the html and css to make edits in this volusion store unfortunately.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. All relevant information to the problem must be in the question itself. Adding a link to your website is not a substitute for a MCVE.

Comment: Is your problem that the class is changing when the value is less than 1 or did you mistype your question? The code works fine for me (in Chrome).

Comment: Also you do not give us any hint what to look for at the site you posted.

Comment: On the site, there is a header icon with a shopping cart and a number of '0'. When you add an item, the number would change to 1,2 etc. At this time, the Js provided up top should execute and set the class of that a tag from 'cart' to 'cart-full' and it is not executing. The 'cart-full' uses a different image.

Comment: the post is updated to make more sense @mplungjan

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the classes when the count of items increases in the SPAN element then you will have to change the addtocart script of your js and that event there. There is a quick alternate way to do what you want by adding an interval that checks the values every second and update classes based on it.
I would not suggest to use the second approach if you know how to manage the add to cart script! 
Try this and it will work.
Example:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  if (parseInt($("span.cart-summary__count").text()) > 0) {
    $("span.cart-summary__count").parent().find('a').removeClass("cart").addClass("cart-full");
  }
},1000);
```

Comment: The first solution is faulty (modification of the _add to cart_ script). User can add few elements to the cart, close the page and then open it again. Number of products will be greater than 0, but the icon of the cart will remain unchanged.

Comment: Oh yeah, add to cart script and a condition in the code in the serverside language.

Comment: There is no option for me to change the add to cart script due to it being a limited editor. It would make it easier if I could. Ill give this a try

Comment: @bldev Yeah that's why I gave you an alternate way so that you can make it work anyway!

Comment: @salil-momin I gave this a try by adding it to a script tag it did not execute.

Comment: I am going to try an onload event to make sure this script will load after the soft_add.js executes

Comment: @bldev I just edited the answer, copy paste the script again and now it will work.  I forgot to add .text() in the IF condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. The problem is the fact that the number of products is retrieved when the DOM is already rendered.

The possible solution is to change the class of the element when the script updates the visible number of products. You are interested in function `itemCount` in the `volusion.js` file:

```
function itemCount(count) {
    if (count === undefined) {
        return currentCartCount;
    } else {
        currentCartCount = count;

        if(currentCartCount > 0) {
            // change style of the cart to full
        } else {
            // change style of the  cart to empty
        }

        $("[data-v-observable='cart-count']").text(count);
        return count;
    }
}
```

---

If you don't have access to all files you can use `DOMSubtreeModified` event:

```
$jQueryModern(document).ready(function() {
    $jQueryModern("#cart-summary").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "span", function() {
      if (parseInt($jQueryModern(this).text()) > 0) {
        $jQueryModern(this).parent().find('a').removeClass("cart");
        $jQueryModern(this).parent().find('a').addClass("cart-full");
      } else {
        $jQueryModern(this).parent().find('a').removeClass("cart-full");
        $jQueryModern(this).parent().find('a').addClass("cart");
      }
    });
});
```

```js
$("#cart-summary").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "span", function() {
  if (parseInt($(this).text()) > 0) {
    $(this).parent().find('a').removeClass("cart");
    $(this).parent().find('a').addClass("cart-full");
  } else {
   $(this).parent().find('a').removeClass("cart-full");
    $(this).parent().find('a').addClass("cart");
  }
});

$('#add').click(function() {
  var newValue = parseInt($("[data-v-observable='cart-count']").text(), 10) + 1;
  $("[data-v-observable='cart-count']").text(newValue);
});

$('#remove').click(function() {
  var newValue = parseInt($("[data-v-observable='cart-count']").text(), 10) - 1;
  if (newValue === -1) newValue = 0;
  $("[data-v-observable='cart-count']").text(newValue);
});
```

```css
.cart-full {
  border: 2px solid red
}

.cartContainer {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart-summary">
  <div class="cartContainer">
    <span class="cart-summary__count" data-v-observable="cart-count">0</span>
    <a href class="cart">example.com</a>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="add">Add item</button>
<button id="remove">Remove item</button>
```

Comment: Due to volusion being an ecommerce store, they really do limit the personal edits. I am only limited to edit the default html page and standard css stylesheets.

Comment: @bldev I have updated my answer to reflect this information, take a look at the second part.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
I am not sure if it is possible to get this to work. I have it saved in the code on the site.

Comment: @bldev this problem is caused by the conflict with other libraries. In the code you have defined `$jQueryModern` as a no-conflict version of jQuery, let's use it. See my updated answer. Replace old code with the new code.